# Insert space to dynamically created select option element before text

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I need create kind of "treeview" look like select element by adding space to the option element text - `<option name='City' />`. My select creating dynamically this way:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Content("~/Home/GetDestinationsTo")",
            data: { 'isRoundTrip': $("input[name='isrt']").is(":checked") ? 2 : 1 },
            type: "post",
            cache: false
        })
            .done(function (result) {
                if (this.Error == null) {
                    optionsto.append($("<option value=''>Куда...</option>"));
                    $.each(result, function () {
                        optionsto.append($("<option name='Country' class='bold info' />").val(this.CountryToId.CountryToId).text(this.CountryToName.CountryToName));
                        optionsto.append($("<option name='City' />").val(this.CityToId.CityToId).text(" " + this.CityToName.CityToName + " (" + this.CityToCode.CityToCode + ")"));
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#errormsg").text(result.Message);
                    $("#modalerror").modal();
                }
            })
            .fail(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                $("#errormsg").text(xhr.responseText);
                $("#modalerror").modal();
            });
```

Finally this must look like `<option text="   SomeCityName"/>`
I suppose only one way is to add HTML presentation of space - `&nbsp;` because add just empty string not working - cut by browser. But it has been added like string, not like HTML and finally look like `&nbsp;CityName`

Comment: why do you even need this leading space?

Comment: @charlietfl - this required by customer.

Comment: But why? If you need padding can do it with css

Comment: @charlietfl, I did tried add margin-left, but seemed like it's not working as well. Not in Chrome at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution, if someone need this:

```
$('select#optionsto > option.city').each(function () {
     $(this).prepend("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only require one level of indent, you can try the `<optgroup>` tag like this:

```
<optgroup label="Group 1">
<option>option 1</option>
<option>option 1</option>
<option>option 1</option>
</optgroup>

<optgroup label="Group 2">
<option>option 1</option>
<option>option 1</option>
<option>option 1</option>
</optgroup>

...
```

Not the same thing exactly but it might work for you.

Comment: Honestly I think the `<select>` control is about the only html element that hasn't been updated in the last ten years. It is by far the most rigid.

There are a few ideas here ( blog.christopherschultz.net/index.php/2009/02/10/indenting-html-select-options/ ) you may want to look at. I think the only way might be to use `&nbsp` but do it like this:
    
    `<option value="blah">&nbsp;SomeCityName</option>` 
    

not like this: `<option text="&nbsp;SomeCityName" />`.